# How to configure Mongodb cache size per database?

Tags: mongodb, performance, caching, database-tuning, wiredtiger

I have two Mongo databases (A and B). Database A is in a place where speed is very important, while B is used in places where speed is not much of an issue.
I would like to somehow limit the size of the available cache for database B, so database A could have a larger portion of it.
In Mongo docs, except changing the size of the whole cache, there isn't much.

Looking through WiredTiger doc I 'v found about [shared cache](https://source.wiredtiger.com/3.1.0/shared_cache.html) which seems it could help but I can not find a way to leverage it through Mongo alone.

Is there a way to limit cache size per database or at least instruct Mongo not to cache certain collections?

Answer (score 2):

`mongod` settings are per-deployment. There is no facility to define how many resources a particular database (or operations on it) can consume.

If you want to control resources per database, each database must be in its own deployment (cluster).